# -bash: /usr/bin/bundle: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm, bundler

When running

```
 $ bundle install
```

I get

```
-bash: /usr/bin/bundle: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I assume it's something to do with my rvm setup. Or my `.bash_profile` $PATH setup.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby` exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably didn't install bundler. Try running `gem install bundler` assuming you installed rubygem!

Comment: Yes. That was it. But I had `bundler` installed before which is why I didn't even think to install it. I've been using it for ever. So some update since  must have removed it.